# Spring how to sync two microservices

Tags: java, spring, queue, microservices, spring-cloud

I have two microservices. `Service #1` puts a certain object in the queue (a table in the database) that needs to be processed. After that, in `service #2`, the sheduler takes new records from the queue every few seconds and processes them, and then saves the result as json to the database. The question is, how do I notify `service #1` about the result of processing?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using any messaging brokers activeMq or rabbitMq. Please refer: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/
Please make use of a rabbitmq receiver to fetch the notification and trigger the processing on you service 1 appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Kafka for your microservice communication. For notifying `service #1` you can send an event from `service #2` through Kafka.
Suppose, from `service #2` you'll send an event named "PROCESSING_DONE" and `service #1` will listen to this event and can do the further processing.

This all will take place in realtime.